# Probability of Point A vs. Point B in a Card Game

Tags: probability

In an imaginary card game, each two cards are dealt to a player and a dealer from a deck of 52 cards (ace has a value of 1, and each face card has a value of 10).

I want to apply combinatoric method to determine the probability of a total of each player/dealer 2-card hand, and ultimately I want to build a 19 x 19 matrix table results for A point vs. B point. For example, for a given hand set, the player hand is A & 7, and the dealer hand is 9 & K, which is a total of 8 vs. 19 (player vs. dealer).

I started out with a combination of 52 card taken 4 at a time -- COMBIN(52,4), which yield a total combination of 270,725, and I’m not sure how to process the 4 dealt cards in each hand set.  What is the proper way to split each 4 dealt cards into a set of two 2-card, and should I apply combination or permutation methodology here?

I need general guidance on how to proceed in determining probability or combination representing A vs. B points for a given hand set.

Comment: Why $21$? The minimum score is 2 and the maximum score is 20, so a 19x19 table would suffice.

Comment: I'll revise my question to reflect the 19 x 19 matrix that you correctly pointed out.

Comment: Since there are (only) 6497400 possibilities, it would be easy to write some code to run through all of them and generate the table.  Would that fit your needs?

Comment: My plan is to programmatically to run through all possible combinations, but I don't know the proper overall combinations for 52/4 cards, and the combinations specifically for each 4 deal cards. How did you come up with 6497400 possibilities?

Comment: $52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49 = 6497400$.

Comment: So let's say the very first 4-card combination out of 6497400 is 1-2-3-4.  How should I split the 1-2-3-4 into a two 2-card hand set?  Should it be 1-2 vs. 3-4.  And why not 2-3 vs. 1-4, or 1-3 vs. 2-4, and so on?  Does this matter? Also, can a symmetrical assumption be valid here (for example, the probability of a 13 vs. 16 is the same as a 16 vs. 13)?

Comment: The 1-2-3-4 should be split based on the rule for dealing, but it doesn't make any difference.  If the deal is always player-dealer-player-dealer, then the 1-2-3-4 has one interpretation.  And yes, due to symmetry 13 vs 16 is the same as 16 vs 13, so your table really only has 190 cases, rather than $19^2$.